# Prestashop google maps API

Tags: api, maps, prestashop

I'm using Prestashop Theme Pts Diana and in my contact page I want to use google maps. There is a module named Pts Map Locator but I cant find where I should put my API key. I tried to add it in StoresController.php file but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to solve this seems to find where is loaded google maps JS and add key parameter like this : //maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=ENTER_KEY_HERE

Dirty solution could be to add to store.tpl the script a second time with the key. It won't kill anyone but it's definitely not a good practice :

```
<script defer async type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;key=ENTER_KEY_HERE"></script>
```